# jquery + html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to get some created tags with jquery

For example :

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var a = this.a;
        var b = this.b;
        var c = this.c;
        $('.info').html("a:" + a + "b:" + b + "c:" + c);
    });
});
```

`<a href="#" a="txt" b="text" c="get">Info</a>`

With this code I get:

`a: undefined b: undefined c: undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            var t = $(this);
            var a = t.attr('a');
            var b = t.attr('b');
            var c = t.attr('c');
            $('.info').html("a:" + a + "b:" + b + "c:" + c);
        });
    });
```

Comment: why make 3 new instances of jQuery?  Use .getAttribute

Comment: @AutoSponge He's not creating 3 new instances, he's creating one (`t`) and reusing it.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) for this:

```
var a = this.getAttribute("a");
var b = this.getAttribute("b");
var c = this.getAttribute("c");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xhBgr/

**Edit**

I'm not sure why everyone is telling you to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) but that is ***very*** relatively expensive compared to getAttribute() (and not wrapping `this` in a jQuery object each time), and it does the exact same thing as getAttribute in this situation. So despite what the majority has said you should use getAttribute().

Here's a benchmark for proof: http://jsperf.com/attrvsget
I got over a 2800% performance boost by using getAttribute method in Chrome.

Comment: I was under the impression that cross-browser compatibility was an issue with getAttribute/hasAttribute(MDN points to using hasattr before getattr). Was I wrong?

Comment: @ChrisBiscardi There are no issues in this situation. The only difference is in some browsers when the attribute doesn't exist it returns null, and in others it returns an empty string. Also in some older versions of IE getAttribute behaves slightly different for the `style` and `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

use `.attr('a', value)` for attributes. `this.a`...`this.c` are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `this` isn't just aware of the attributes to turn them directly into properties, you must "find" them, using jQuery's [`attr(name)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method for example:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('a');
    var b = $(this).attr('b');
    var c = $(this).attr('c');
    $('.info').html("a:" + a + "b:" + b + "c:" + c);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get attributes like this:

```
$('a').attr('href')
```

here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
    $('a').click(function() { 
        var a = $(this).attr("a"); 
        var b = $(this).attr("b");
        var c = $(this).attr("c"); 
        $('.info').html("a:" + a + "b:" + b + "c:" + c); 
    }); 
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/S4svg/

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
    var a = this.a;
    var b = this.b;
    var c = this.c;
```

To:

```
    var $this = $(this),
        a = $this.attr('a'),
        b = $this.attr('b'),
        c = $this.attr('c');
```

Notice I cached the `$(this)` selector so we only have to handle the overhead of selecting a DOM element once. I also chain together the variable declarations using commas rather than using the `var` keyword repeatedly.

Also it's a good idea to use `data-attributes` to make sure you are using names that are unique. So instead of:

```
<a href="#" a="txt" b="text" c="get">Info</a>
```

Try:

```
<a href="#" data-a="txt" data-b="text" data-c="get">Info</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HGRfC/

it's an attribute, not a property.